# Data shows on server response, but not on browser - MySQL Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

When I run `http://localhost:1337` I get this as my output `Hello, [object Object]` but on the server response, the output is `Hello, David James`. It works on the server response but not on the browser.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'mywebsite'
});

connection.connect(function(error) {
    if(!!error) {
        console.log('Error');
    } else {
        console.log('Connected');
    }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    connection.query("SELECT Name FROM chat", function(error, rows, fields) {
        if(!!error) {
            console.log('Error in the query');
        } else {
            console.log('SUCCESS!\n');
            console.log(rows);
            res.send('Hello, ' + rows);
        }
    });
});

app.listen(1337);
```

Comment: show your html part too please

Comment: My HTML is empty. It's printing out from app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send it back with `JSON.stringify`

```
res.send('Hello, ' + JSON.stringify(rows))
```